# Scrapy- How to extract all blog posts from a category?

Tags: python, regex, wordpress, scrapy

I am using scrapy to extract all the posts of my blog. The problem is I cannot figure out how to create a rule that reads all the posts in any given blog category?

example: On my blog the category, "Environment setup" has 17 posts. So in the scrapy code I can hard code it as given but this is not a very practical approach

```
start_urls=["https://edumine.wordpress.com/category/ide- configuration/environment-setup/","https://edumine.wordpress.com/category/ide-configuration/environment-setup/page/2/","https://edumine.wordpress.com/category/ide-configuration/environment-setup/page/3/"]
```

I have read similar posts related to this question posted here on SO like [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19086113/scrapy-does-not-crawl-after-first-page?rq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20598606/how-to-use-scrapy-to-crawl-multiple-pages), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19001826/scrapy-recursive-link-crawler), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=scrapy%20how%20to%20scrape%20all%20webpage), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17509636/scrapy-recursive-download-of-content), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22182312/recursive-scraping-on-craigslist-with-scrapy?rq=1), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21672636/yield-multiple-items-using-scrapy), but I cant seem to find out my answer in any. As you can see, the only difference is the page count in the above url's. How can I write a rule in scrapy that can read all the blog posts in a category. And another trivial question, how can I configure the spider to crawl my blog such that when I post a new blog post entry, the crawler can immediately detect it an write it to a file.

This is what I have so far for the spider class

```
from BlogScraper.items import BlogscraperItem
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request


class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "nextpage" # give your spider a unique name because it will be used for crawling the webpages

    #allowed domain restricts the spider crawling
    allowed_domains=["https://edumine.wordpress.com/"]
    # in start_urls you have to specify the urls to crawl from
    start_urls=["https://edumine.wordpress.com/category/ide-configuration/environment-setup/"]

    '''
    start_urls=["https://edumine.wordpress.com/category/ide-configuration/environment-setup/",
                "https://edumine.wordpress.com/category/ide-configuration/environment-setup/page/2/",
                "https://edumine.wordpress.com/category/ide-configuration/environment-setup/page/3/"]


    rules = [
                Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor
                    (allow=("https://edumine.wordpress.com/category/ide-configuration/environment-setup/\d"),unique=False,follow=True))
            ]
'''
    rules= Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='https://edumine.wordpress.com/category/ide-configuration/environment-setup/page/'),follow=True,callback='parse_page')

    def parse_page(self, response):

        hxs=Selector(response)
        titles = hxs.xpath("//h1[@class='entry-title']")
        items = []
        with open("itemLog.csv","w") as f:
             for title in titles:
                item = BlogscraperItem()
                item["post_title"] = title.xpath("//h1[@class='entry-title']//text()").extract()
                item["post_time"] = title.xpath("//time[@class='entry-date']//text()").extract()
                item["text"]=title.xpath("//p//text()").extract()
                item["link"] = title.select("a/@href").extract()

                items.append(item)

                f.write('post title: {0}\n, post_time: {1}\n, post_text: {2}\n'.format(item['post_title'], item['post_time'],item['text']))
                print "#### \tTotal number of posts= ",len(items), " in category####"


        f.close()
```

Any help or suggestions to solve it?

Comment: Since wordpress stores posts in a database, why don't you use the database instead of scrapy?

Comment: Because, I would like the spider to crawl not only my blog but other blogs too and I think for that reason alone scrapy is the best candidate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some things you can improve in your code and two problems you want to solve: reading posts, automatic crawling.

If you want to get the contents of a new blog post you have to re-run your spider. Otherwise you would have an endless loop. Naturally in this case you have to make sure that you do not scrape already scraped entries (database, read available files at spider start and so on). But you cannot have a spider which runs forever and waits for new entries. This is not the purpose.

Your approach to store the posts into a file is wrong. This means why do you scrape a list of items and then do nothing with them? And why do you save the items in the `parse_page` function? For this there are [item pipelines](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#writing-your-own-item-pipeline), you should write one and do there the exporting. And the `f.close()` is not necessary because you use the `with` statement which does this for you at the end.

Your `rules` variable should throw an error because it is not iterable. I wonder if you even tested your code. And the Rule is too complex. You can simplify it to this:

```
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(allow='page/*'), follow=True, callback='parse_page'),]
```

And it follows every URL which has `/page` in it.

If you start your scraper you will see that the results are filtered because of your allowed domains:

```
Filtered offsite request to 'edumine.wordpress.com': <GET https://edumine.wordpress.com/category/ide-configuration/environment-setup/page/2/>
```

To solve this change your domain to:

```
allowed_domains = ["edumine.wordpress.com"]
```

If you want to get other wordpress sites, change it simply to

```
allowed_domains = ["wordpress.com"]
```

Comment: A quintal of thanks to you @GHajba for such an elaborate answer. Thank you for pointing out the mistakes and their possible solutions. It is very enriching. I have just started with scrapy so the architecture is still not clear. Any good reference that easy to understand about the item pipelines would be appreciated. The official documentation is a bit to heavy for me to grasp as of now. Yes the rules variable was throwing an error, but I had no clue how to fix it.

Comment: Another related question is that sometimes if the blog post is too long then we see a url link like 'Continue Reading', clicking it takes to the full post. How do I go about coding it in xpath?

Comment: There are several approaches. I won't code it in XPath but in the `parse_page` to see if the content contains the link. If yes I would `yield` a new `Request` to the detailed article with another parser function which scrapes the detailed post. In this case I won't `yield` the `item` found. This is one approach.

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. Let me try this. I might come back here again if I cannot get it to work. fingers crossed, I hope I can get this to work.

Comment: I am wondering how do I go about checking for new post published such that the scraper only writes the new post to the already existing file of old posts? Any suggestion on how to accomplish this feat?