# Scrapy- How to check for a new blog post published?

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

Scrapy is quite an interesting framework.
A couple of questions I now have:

1) In an [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818729/scrapy-how-to-extract-all-blog-posts-from-a-category), I figured out how to extract all blog posts using scrapy but there is a glitch in the solution. You see, a blog post typically has a url "continue reading" which when clicked shows you the complete post. So how do I extract the complete post?..This is [my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32818729/scrapy-how-to-extract-all-blog-posts-from-a-category)

2) How can I code the spider to check for a new blog post using scrapy?

3) How do i clean the extracted data? One approach I thought was to import regular expression library in the spider class of scrapy. But when I try the crawling I get an import error that regex module not found? So does that mean I cannot do the data cleaning in the spider? Do i have a to write a separate class for it?

Any suggestions?

Comment: To check for new blog post, you'd need to extract data from RSS feed of blog. If you are not limited to scrapy there are couple of software to schedule extraction, and clean the data as well. Like http://datascraping.co , import.io and Kimono

Comment: @VikashRathee thanks for taking the time to reply. But, I am searching for the underlying logic that can do this task and not some software API.